# How to select distinct rows in 2 columns and sort both individually

Tags: mysql, sql, select, grouping, columnsorting

I have this sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT car_year, car_make 
FROM cars
GROUP BY car_year, car_make 
ORDER BY car_year ASC, car_make ASC
```

It returns this:

```
car_year | car_make
-------------------
    2009 | TOYOTA
    2011 | AUDI
    2013 | ACURA
    2014 | AUDI
    2015 | KIA
    2015 | ACURA
```

I need it to be more unique (distinct) and almost make it as individual lists, even though these are stored in same table (cars). Something like this:

```
car_year | car_make
-------------------
    2009 | ACURA
    2011 | AUDI
    2013 | KIA
    2014 | TOYOTA
    2015 |
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?, why not just do 2 separate select distinct statements?

Comment: You have removed the relation of data. Is that what you need?

Comment: I want 2 columns to be sorted and selected

Comment: but they no longer have anything to do with each other the way your output looks, is it important that they be in the same result set? Why?

Comment: I'm trying to glue them back in php and process this in array. I haven't thought to do 2 separate statements, but i'd rather do 1. May be some kind of join would solve this?

Comment: There is no 2009 Acura for example in your original, why would you want 2009 Acura in the result?  You don't I imagine, hence 2 separate lists, manipulate them in code however you need.

Comment: I want to pull the list of inventory that I already have, but individually. I only care about all years in cars and all makes in cars, they don't have to be linked between each other in any way

Comment: Well, why do you list `DESC` on `car_make` if your desired output is `ASC`

Comment: and by the way, the `SELECT DISTINCT` is keeping all of your records because each row is technically `DISTINCT` because of the year column.

Comment: @Mark LaREZZA it was a mistype. Thank you, just fixed order by

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/519e4/16
Run each query separately and look at the results.
The reason we can't combine the data is because the columns are of 2 different data types and we can't join on anything. (No apparent PK?)..Hopefully someone will come along with a better solution. There are people way more experienced with SQL than I. It seems like SQLFiddle is hiding the other query -> SELECT DISTINCT year FROM test order by year

Comment: @MarkLaREZZA, Thanks for the detailed explanation. That's pretty much what I ended up doing. I used Daniel's answer and built 2 separate queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT car_year
FROM cars
ORDER BY car_year

SELECT DISTINCT  car_make 
FROM cars
ORDER BY car_make
```

Comment: Why does he need DISTINCT on the car year? The data shows no repeating years.

Comment: because i would imagine he has more than 5 rows of real data.

Comment: Yes, and it would all be years, something like the column name

Comment: and 2015 is there twice actually.

Comment: Son of a... Nice catch. My mistake

Comment: he wants one entry per year, not every year record he has. I dont understand the question you are posing.

Comment: I totally overlooked the repeating years.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  SELECT  car_year, car_make 
  FROM <tablename>
  GROUP BY car_make, car_year 
  ORDER BY car_year ASC, car_make DESC
```

Comment: It's the same thing that I already tried, except where clause removed

Comment: i changed the order , just look

Comment: This isn't really what I want. I want to get every year, sorted ASC and every make sorted ASC and no duplicate values under each column